# how to remove wild characters from mysql

Tags: mysql, php4

somehow wild characters has cropped up in my mysql table while storing UNC path in my table. 
and all the \r onces are showing up a square in the fields. Can anyone tell me how to fix these please?
Thanks.

Comment: Was this the result of an SQL injection attack, perhaps? If so, more repair may be needed than just fixing that one table, and prevention would need to be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)